# EPPlus clone worksheet

Tags: c#, epplus, npoi

I want to clone worksheet int my excel template file programatically. When Using NPOI library I can use

```
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs, true);
    workbook.CloneSheet(1);
```

I wonder is there something equivalent to that with EPPlus `ExcelWorkbook`. I want to copy overall `ExcelWorksheet` to keep my format and value, not just copy each cell or range of cell manually

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the `ExcelWorksheets.Copy` method:

```
public ExcelWorksheet Copy(ExcelWorkbook workbook, string existingWorksheetName, string newWorksheetName)
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Copy(existingWorksheetName, newWorksheetName);
    return worksheet;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

first u need to open both of workbooks and then u can add the whole worksheet:
(example: copy from workbook_1 -> workbook_2)

```
FileInfo existingFile1 = new FileInfo(path_of_workbook_1);
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile1 ))
{
     FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(path_of_workbook_2);
     using (ExcelPackage package_0 = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
     {
         ExcelWorksheet worksheet0 = package_0.Workbook.Worksheets["Original Sheet"];
         package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Copied Sheet", worksheet0);
     }
}
```